# iFrame Black Box While Loading?

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iFrame in a page. When the page is loading the iFrame shows as a black box until it is also loaded. This is visually distracting. How do I prevent a black box from showing while the page loads?

iFrame Code + CSS:

```
<iframe class="iframe-email-signup" frameborder="0" src="/src.html"></iframe>

/* CSS for above Class */

.iframe-email-signup{
   max-height:7em;
   background: none !important;
}
```

The site that is having the problem is: http://www.checkplusbalance.com/

It is the email signup box that is below the main text you see on the opening site.

Comment: you may set `visibitily: hidden` and reset it it `visible` after the frame is loaded

Comment: That black background is caused by the CSS of the page that is being loaded inside the IFRAME. Setting background styles in the outer page on the IFRAME element itself won't help you here. Can you edit the CSS of the inner page?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Yes I can. The inner page is set to `background: none !important;`

Comment: @Lynda You have to find where the black background is set in the CSS of the inner page. It has to be somewhere, either on the HTML element, or the BODY, or some DIV…

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - I tried this code: `*{background: none !important;}` and that didn't work. I cannot find what is causing this issue.

Comment: @Lynda Is that page online? If yes, I can look into it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - It isn't public yet. When it is I will add a link. Thanks for the offer.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Site is live. Link was added in question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to solve the black box problem. I couldn't find a CSS only solution so I resorted to JS to show the iFrame only after the iFrame has loaded.

***iFrame Code***

```
<iframe id="iFrameID" frameborder="0" src="src.html"></iframe>
```

***CSS***

```
#iFrameID{
   display:none;
}
```

***JS***

```
$(function() {
   $("#iFrameID").on('load', function () {
       $("#iFrameID").fadeIn("fast");
   });
});
```

**Note:**

If a user has JS disabled the iFrame will not show. In my case the content of the iFrame won't work without JS enabled so I am okay with this.

There are other workarounds to hide the iFrame using JS so if a user doesn't have JS they still see the iFrame. You can also have a duplicate iFrame wrapped in `<noscript>` tags. I chose the method that works the best for my situation.